# How should regulation "part" tags be named?

Tags: discussion, tags

As an example, we now have [faa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations), but there are many parts to the FAA regulations, such as 14 CFR 61/91/121/135/etc.

The regulations that apply are to something can be very different depending on what part applies, so we have tags for them.  Right now FAA tags are named like [far-91](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/far-91) but what would be the best naming scheme for them?  FAR is a (commonly used) nickname for "14 CFR", but is not the official term.

Since [faa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations) is so commonly used, I would like to see the tag name begin with "faa" so that we can see a list of the tags that are used together when we first start typing the regulatory authority tag name.  This would be particularly for less commonly used/known regulations in that someone can simply enter the regulatory authority tag and see the major parts of their regulations as well.  Some suggestions:

- [faa-14cfr135](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-14cfr135) (my personal favorite since it is the "official" way) or
- [faa-part135](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-part135) or
- [faa-far135](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-far135) or
- [faa-far-part-135](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-far-part-135) or
- [faa-regulations-part135](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations-part135) or
- ???

Comment: Personally, I prefer `faa-part135` because it sounds more like something one would use, but I have no _particular_ objections to `faa-14cfr135`. `faa-far135` feels a bit redundant, and the others sound too verbose for my liking.

Comment: I agree with @Qantas94Heavy that `faa-far135` is redundant and prefer `faa-part135`. From a non-technical standpoint as a long time private pilot, I would never think to use `faa-14cfr135` when asking a question and I rarely see that nomenclature used in general aviation in the US.

Comment: @Magnetoz In the US true, but internationally most people seem to know 14 CFR 135.  Also, while you might not think to use it, when you start typing "faa" it will list your options out and you can pick the one that you see.

Answer (score 5):

Those in favor of [faa-part135](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-part135) vote here.

(Feel free to add your own suggestions too!)

Answer (score 2):

Those in favor of [faa-14cfr135](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-14cfr135) vote here.

Consider this as having one extra +1 since I can't upvote my own answer, lol!

(Feel free to add your own suggestions too!)

Comment: This one is now 3+1 :) though it needs spaces (dashes) IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer [faa-far-135](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-far-135).

This should show up when people type "FAA" or "FAR" in the tag box which will help with visibility.
If someone asks about the older Civil Air Regulations an analogous [faa-car-3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-car-3) etc. could be created.

("FAR" may not be an "official" abbreviation for 14CFR, but [even the FAA uses it](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/faa_regulations/) - "Look up FARs" in the right-hand box. The "FAA" bit disambiguates *whose* federal air regulations we're talking about.)

Comment: True, although we could have tag synonyms to help with visibility as well.  Ie [tag:far-91] -> [tag:faa-14cfr91]